# datauris: are PNG and JPEG MIME types interchangable in modern browsers?

Tags: data-uri

I have noticed that if you take a base64 string representing the raw bytes of either a JPG or a PNG, call this `<B>`, and you send a datauri to the browser using *either*:

```
data:image/png;base64,<B>
```

or

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,<B>
```

*all four* combinations work (by work I mean Chrome renders them), the four combinations being

1. `<B>` is raw png image, and the data uri uses the `png` type
2. `<B>` is raw png image, and the data uri uses the `jpeg` type (was expecting a failure!)
3. `<B>` is raw jpeg image and the data uri uses the `png` type (was expecting a failure!)
4. `<B>` is raw jpeg image, and the data uri uses the `jpeg` type

Why is this? The binary encoding of jpeg and png are not the same. I was expecting that if `<B>` was the raw bytes of a png, the jpeg datauri would fail to render, and visa versa.

Comment: Browsers are designed to try to fix all crap and recover from all conceivable errors (tag soup rulez!). It looks easy to recover from a failed graphic format decoding and it's equally simple to do signature based file format detection for pictures.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález if that is the case, why can't the dataURI MIME type inclusion be removed?

Comment: What'd be point of being forcibly unable to declare content type? A data URI can potentially contain any of [1000+ MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), many of which can't even be reliably detected with signature based heuristics. It'd be the equivalent of not having file extensions in the files you have in your hard disc.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález but in this case, I am forcibly telling the browser the MIME type, which I expected to fail (in the bad case), but it "decides to go further" and just try other MIME types? I would be ok with the signature based guessing game in the case where I do not pass the MIME type, but not in the case where the MIME is passed in by the user

Comment: That's what my two comments mean. You do need type info. But when it's wrong, browsers try to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Data URLs are described in the [RFC 2397 proposed standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) (*The "data" URL scheme*) from August 1998:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

This document doesn't really go into implementation details such as error handling.

It's worth noting that the media type part is optional and defaults to plain text in 7-bit US-ASCII:

> If `<mediatype>` is omitted, it defaults to `text/plain;charset=US-ASCII`.

Now, from the context of your question I assume you're really talking about HTML documents and `<img>` tags. Whether the information inside the `src` attribute comes from an inline data URL string or an HTTP network request is possibly secondary and I suspect that raw binary data is handled by the same routines inside the browser no matter its source.

You can emulate the same behaviour by sending arbitrary `Content-Type` headers with regular image files. This can be accomplished by (mis)configuring your web server, writing a download script in a server-side language or just renaming the files. And in fact you don't even need HTML:

[image: Firefox Developer Tools with fake GIF]

In short, it all relates to the ability of browsers to recover from error conditions that arises from the [fundamental design philosophy of the World Wide Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup), which kind of evolved organically.